# Access to keyboard function keys

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard

I'm planning to use function keys on the Apple Pro keyboard in an admin program I'm designing, but I'm having a hard time finding out where to start. There must be some obvious high level API I'm missing here.

Comment: Can you plz add some more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything in the [responder chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW10) gets a [`-keyDown:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/keyDown%3a) message when a key is pressed. See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH7-SW16) for Apple's documentation on how to interpret certain physical keys. You're looking for the keys starting at [`NSF1FunctionKey`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-SW136).

Comment: Thanks. It was really that simple.